# Chess Gui change player with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, chess

The problem is that it doesn't cange player whenever i change player

Edit: I edited the code.

This function create the case of the board, it's only half the code because it's the same for every pieces:

```
def cree_case(ligne, colonne):

    case = Canvas(frame, width=100, height = 100,highlightthickness=1,highlightbackground="black")
    def click(event):
        joue(ligne,colonne)
    def click2(event):
        label_joueur["text"]="cchzohdc" 
        joue2(ligne,colonne,l,c,joue)
    label_joueur["text"]=("choissisez une piece")
    case.bind('<Button-1>',click)
    case.bind('<Button-3>',click2)
    x, y = 55, 55
    if board[ligne][colonne][0]== "F" and board[ligne][colonne][2]=="W":
        case.create_image(x,y,image=fou_blanc)
    elif board[ligne][colonne][0]== "F" and board[ligne][colonne][2]=="N":
        case.create_image(x,y,image=fou_noir)
```

Here si the three function, that i use to play and make to movement aswell changing player:

```
def joue(ligne, colonne):
    global l,c
    print( ligne, colonne)
    l,c= ligne,colonne

def player(): # cette fonction permet de jouer et changer de joueur
    if joueur == "joueur1":
        return "joueur2"
    elif joueur=="joueur2":
        return "joueur1"
def joue2(ligne,colonne,l,c,joue,):
     player()
     m=ligne
     n=colonne
    if not est_valide(joueur,l,c,m,n) or not pion_valide(l,c,m,n,joueur) or not dame_valide(l,c,m,n,joueur) or not  fou_valide(l,c,m,n) or not roi_valide(l,c,m,n) or not  cavalier_valide(l,c,m,n) or not tour_valide(l,c,m,n,joueur) or not  pion_valide(l,c,m,n,joueur)  :
        print("mauvais")
        faux=Toplevel(Fenetre, height= 100, width = 100)
        case1 = Canvas(faux, width=100, height     100,highlightthickness=1,highlightbackground="black")
        v= 50 
        w= 50
        case1.create_image(v,w,image=stop)
        case1.grid()
        faux.mainloop()
    elif est_victorieux(joueur):
        board[m][n]=board[l][c]
        board[l][c]="___"
        frame.destroy()
        label_joueur["text"]=("Echec et mat")
    else:
        board[m][n]=board[l][c]
        board[l][c]="___"
        if est_victorieux(joueur):
            frame.destroy()
            label_joueur["text"]=("Echec et mat")
        else:
            affiche_grille()


joueur="joueur1"
affiche_grille()
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? What is preventing you from changing the player?

Comment: I added print(joueur) to player(), player does shows "joueur1" but  it shows everytime "joueur1"

Comment: This is because you have joueur="joueur1" inside the function player.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the function `player` you don't assign the return to any variable.

```
def click3(event):
    player(joueur)
```

You use the variable `joueur` in the function `player` to check which player is active, but when you assign a new value to `joueur` you do it in the **local scope**, which means that this assignment will not affect the global variable.

Sooo..., you'll have to harvest the return from `player` or make the variable `joueur` global.

**Answer update**

I have reduced the code to the bare minimum to show the mechanism. This can be done in many ways, I'm choosing one of them.

You don't need to give `joueur` as an argument to the function `player()`. You only have **one** variable that indicates which player is active so it should be easy to kep track of. When you run a function it will look for the variable `joueur` inside the function, but if it doesn't find it there it will look in the global scope.

The function `player()` does not change the variable `joueur`, it just returns a value. The statement `joueur = player(joueur)` assigns the new value to the global variable `joueur`.

```
def click3(event):  # Callback for middle mouse button
    return player() # Change player

def player(): # cette fonction permet de jouer et changer de joueur
    if joueur == "joueur1":
        return "joueur2"    # Return the other player
    else:
        return "joueur1"    # Return the other player

joueur = "joueur1"  # Variable joueur in the global scope
print(joueur)

# Switch player a couple of times and print it
joueur = player() 
print(joueur)
joueur = player()
print(joueur)
joueur = player()
print(joueur)
```

Comment: When i put `return joueur`, it does change player to "joueur2" but the thing is that it stays as "joueur2". It doesn't change evreytime i play

Comment: Ok it does change player whenever I play again, I added `joueur=player()` in the function `affiche_grille()` and `print(joueur)` but  i still play as "joueur1", because the function `joue2` take the first assignement i did `joueur="joueur1"` as the player name.

Comment: I don't use `click3(event)` because i think only adding `player()` to `affiche_grille` is needed.

Comment: Sorry, but if you want help with some code, please provide the code you want help with. As your code also was incomplete (does not run) i tried to explain a mechanism. Do you understand how it works?

Answer (score -1):

So i finally made it work, I just added this:

```
if joueur == "joueur1":
    joueur = "joueur2"
    label_joueur["text"] = joueur #This is optionnal, it's just details
else:
    joueur = "joueur1"
    label_joueur["text"] = joueur
```

To the `joue2(ligne,colonne,l,c,joue)`like that:

```
def joue2(ligne,colonne,l,c,joue):
    global joueur
    m=ligne
    n=colonne
    if not est_valide(joueur,l,c,m,n) or not pion_valide(l,c,m,n,joueur) or not dame_valide(l,c,m,n,joueur) or not  fou_valide(l,c,m,n) or not roi_valide(l,c,m,n) or not  cavalier_valide(l,c,m,n) or not tour_valide(l,c,m,n,joueur) or not  pion_valide(l,c,m,n,joueur)  :
        print("mauvais")
        faux=Toplevel(Fenetre, height= 100, width = 100)
        case1 = Canvas(faux, width=100, height = 100,highlightthickness=1,highlightbackground="black")
        v= 50 
        w= 50
        case1.create_image(v,w,image=stop)
        case1.grid()
        faux.mainloop()
    elif est_victorieux(joueur):
        board[m][n]=board[l][c]
        board[l][c]="___"
        frame.destroy()
        label_joueur["text"]=("Echec et mat")
    else:
        board[m][n]=board[l][c]
        board[l][c]="___"
        if est_victorieux(joueur):
            frame.destroy()
            label_joueur["text"]=("Echec et mat")
        else:
            if joueur == "joueur1":
                joueur = "joueur2"
                label_joueur["text"] = joueur
            else:
                joueur = "joueur1"
                label_joueur["text"] = joueur
        affiche_grille()
```

You need to add global joueur to make this work.

Comment: Is this intended as an answer to the question? If so, it would be much better if you explained what you did differently. Otherwise we have to compare this code to the original line by line and character by character.

Comment: Not an answer just the current code, it still doesn't work

Comment: The answer section is only for answers. If you need to provide additional information, edit your question.